# Reading YAML file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, yaml

I apologize for the amateur question, I'm still learning. I'm trying to pull information from a YAML file in Ruby. I thought that because I had pushed the information to an array, all I would have to is print the array. I know that's not the case, but I couldn't find anything in the documentation when I looked.

```
require "yaml"

class BankAccount

attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name, :address, :your_account

def initialize
    @your_account = []
    open()
end

def open
    if File.exist?("accountinfo.yml")
    @your_account = YAML.load_file("accountinfo.yml")
    end
end

def save
    File.open("accountinfo.yml", "r+") do |file|
        file.write(your_account.to_yaml)
    end
end

def new_account(first_name, last_name, address)
    puts "Enter your first name:"
    first_name = gets.chomp
    puts "Enter your last name"
    last_name = gets.chomp
    puts "Enter your address:"
    address = gets.chomp
end

def account_review(your_account)
    puts @your_acccount
end

def run
    loop do
        puts "Welcome to the bank."
        puts "1. Create New Account"
        puts "2. Review Your Account Information"
        puts "3. Check Your Balance"
        puts "4. Exit"
        puts "Enter your choice:"
            input = gets.chomp
            case input
            when '1'
                new_account(first_name, last_name, address)
            when '2'
                account_review(your_account)
            when '4'
                save()
                break
            end
    end
end

end
bank_account = BankAccount.new
bank_account.run
```

Comment: What is your actual problem? Do you get an error, is the file empty, how does the content of the file look?

Comment: Could you post the contents of accountinfo.yml too please?

Comment: The file is created in the folder, but when the program runs and I try and select the option to read the information, it doesn't execute. I'm not sure if the information is stored in the file or not. I can't tell if I'm not loading the file right, and that's the reason it's not displaying, or if the program just created the file but never wrote to it at all.

Comment: Edit: I opened the accounting.yml file and there's nothing there. Just the empty array.

Comment: I've left an answer for you that should help. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

When I'm facing something like this, I find it easiest to use `irb` to see what a YAML file looks like after it is loaded. Sometimes it can be in a format subtly different to what you were expecting.

In the same directory, on the command line, run `irb`.

You then have an interactive Ruby console where you can run commands.

`require 'pp'` - this helps you see output more easily.

Then:

```
your_account = YAML.load_file("accountinfo.yml")
pp your_account
```

In the code above, it appears that in your new_account method, you're not actually setting these attributes on @your_account, and in the save method you're writing an undefined variable to yaml.

Save should be:

```
file.write(@your_account.to_yaml)
```

New account should end with:

```
@your_account[:first_name] = first_name
@your_account[:last_name] = last_name
@your_account[:address] = address
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Rails, here's an easy way to read a YAML file (what the title says)

```
# Load the whatever_config from whatever.yml
whatever_config = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read(Rails.root.join("config/whatever.yml"))).result)[Rails.env]

# Extract the foo variable out
foo = whatever_config['foo']
```

I don't think I really understand what your question is, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You never actually set your variables. Prefix the setter with `self.`, otherwise you would just create a local variable with the same name. Furthermore you don't set your `your_acccount` at all:

```
def new_account
  puts "Enter your first name:"
  self.first_name = gets.chomp
  puts "Enter your last name"
  self.last_name = gets.chomp
  puts "Enter your address:"
  self.address = gets.chomp

  self.your_account = [first_name, last_name, address]
end
```

Another issue will be that your code never calls `open`. That means everything works fine until you end program and restart it. Just call `open` before you call `account_review` to fix that.

Comment: For my own clarification, using the "self" prefix creates a class variable instead of a local variable?

Comment: Nope, using `self` tells Ruby to look for a method with that name (that exists, because you created that method with `attr_accessor`) instead of just creating a local variable. Basically you have two options to set an instance variables: 1) Directly by calling `@variable_name=` or 2) by calling `self.variable_name=` if you have a setter method.